# How to combine two rows of data from the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table called document as follow:

**document_table**

- document_id
- employee_id
- type (values can be *"transcript"* or *"testimonial"*)
- status ( value can be *"ready to print" only*

Sample data as below.

```
doc_id   employee_id   type         status
--------------------------------------------------
1        S1234         transcript   ready to print
2        S1234         testimonial  ready to print
3        S2345         transcript   ready to print
```

I want result table to be like below.

**Result_table**:

- employee_id
- transcript
- testimonial

I would like to write a sql query to combine the individual document records into one, based on employee_id, and based on the document type being either transcript or testimonial

```
doc_id  transcript     testimonial
--------------------------------
S1234   TRUE           TRUE
S2345   TRUE           FALSE
```

I'm using MS Access 2010.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Based on the sample data you gave, what is your desired output?

Comment: @waka the result table is my desired output

Comment: then... why don't you create a view?

Comment: @rmjoia I’m not sure what you mean by a view. I’m trying to write a sql query to get that result from my document table. But I’m not sure how to go about writing it

Comment: Then, explain yourself better, you have one table source, and one "result" I can see that the "S1234" (id??) is in both tables.. but I can't figure out where did the TRUE, FALSE came from.. you got to help us help you

Comment: I apologise for the poor explanation, really new to this. Document.type can be “transcript” or “testimonial”. I would like the result table to show, for an employee id, whether he has a transcript and/or a testimonial. This is based on the records in the document table. If he has a transcript, the result table will show TRUE under the transcript column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach, although will only return `TRUE` where there is data, `FALSE` will just be empty field:

```
TRANSFORM First("TRUE") AS S
SELECT document.employee_id
FROM document
GROUP BY document.employee_id
PIVOT document.type In ("testimonial","transcript");
```

Don't think Access SQL recognizes the `CASE` structure, so alternate version of zarruq answer:

```
SELECT
  employee_id,
  IIf(Max(transcript)="transcript","TRUE","FALSE") AS tran, 
  IIf(Max(testimonial)="testimonial", "TRUE","FALSE") AS test
FROM (SELECT
  employee_id,
  type AS transcript,
  '' AS testimonial
FROM document
WHERE type = 'transcript'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  employee_id,
  '' AS transcript,
  type AS testimonial
FROM document
WHERE type = 'testimonial')
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SQL`, One approach could be to separate `transcript` and `testimonial` data in separate columns using `union` in inner query and then use `max` and `case` in outer query as below to get your desired result as below.

```
SELECT
  employee_id,
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(transcript) = 'transcript' THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS transcript,
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(testimonial) = 'testimonial' THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS testimonial
FROM (SELECT
  employee_id,
  type AS transcript,
  '' AS testimonial
FROM t1
WHERE type = 'transcript'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  employee_id,
  '' AS transcript,
  type AS testimonial
FROM t1
WHERE type = 'testimonial') t
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

**Result:**

```
employee_id    transcript   testimonial
---------------------------------------
S1234          TRUE         TRUE
S2345          TRUE         FALSE
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/ZMMEUQ29850)**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! But I’m afraid the syntax doesn’t work for access.